# Check if string doesn't exist in List

Tags: python

I have a List of Strings in Python and I want to check if the string "EVN" does not exist in the range `segmentList[x][0:3]`, so I can create it in a specific place in the list.

I'm trying to check if the string in this range (`segmentType = segmentList[x][0:3]`) in the list and if it doesn't I want to call a method `create_EVN()` and insert the "EVN" string into the second position of the list moving up the other elements rather that deleting them.

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to find the most efficient way possible to do this. I have tried looping through the list with no avail.

Comment: Did you try `not in`?

Comment: Never used that key word but I will have a look, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
if 'EVN' not in segmentList[x][0:3] :
    create_EVN()
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this. It should work but in this case it will check the first line (x) then call the create message - what if the EVN string exists on the second line of the list. Therefore it needs to check every line of the list then call the create method if its not on any line.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
if 'EVN' not in segmentList[x][0:3]:
   create_EVN()
```